# Only generate positive integers with QuickCheck

Tags: haskell, testing, quickcheck

We have two functions that compare two different `power` functions, and return true if they return the same value (on the same input).

Then we have two other functions that test these functions against two lists to see if there is any value that doesn't return true.

But instead of using lists that use a range `[1..100]`, we would like to use QuickCheck.

Is it possible to make QuickCheck only return positive integers?

Code:

```
comparePower1 :: Integer -> Integer -> Bool
comparePower1 n k = power n k == power1 n k

comparePower2 :: Integer -> Integer -> Bool
comparePower2 n k = power n k == power2 n k

testing1 = and [comparePower1 n k | n <- [0..100], k <- [0..100]]
testing2 = and [comparePower2 n k | n <- [0..100], k <- [0..100]]
```

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466580/how-to-use-modifiers-with-quickcheck-positive-in-my-case will help ?

Comment: @TomaszLewowski Not really. I did not understand this type class/definition `(Integral a, Show a, Read a) => ...`

Comment: how about using `suchThat` modifier for generator?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

QuickCheck has support for [Positive numbers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.9.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#t:Positive), but for the sake of this tutorial I will show you how to create your own Generator. One of the main features of QuickCheck is that you can design your own generator to output just what you need. For instance

```
genPos :: Gen Int
genPos = abs `fmap` (arbitrary :: Gen Int) `suchThat` (> 0)
```

Then you can create your own list genereator

```
genListOfPos :: Gen [Int]
genListOfPos = listOf genPos
```

Finally you can use forAll, pass the generator and profit.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  quickCheck $ forAll genPos $ \x -> x > 0
  quickCheck $ forAll genListOfPos $ all (> 0)
```

Comment: Thx, it worked! A question: Why dont I need to apply the new list to the testing function, or atleast delete the existing list there (`[1..100]`)? Or maybe my question should be, what exactly is that function with that list doing now?

Comment: `all (> 0)` expands to `\xs -> all (\x -> x > 0) xs` which means apply `\x -> x > 0` to each element of `xs` and then run `all` to check if all elements are `True`

Comment: For the sake of efficiency, it might be better to generate a `Word`, add 1, cast to `Int`, take the absolute value, and then toss zero. The reason this *might* be better is that I believe QuickCheck normally tries to choose mostly "small" values, so you could have a lot of zeros to throw away. You'd have to check some details before taking this advice, however--I could be wrong.

Comment: It would be nice to try if this is true. Another solution is to just add 1 to the generated number (except if it's `maxBound :: int`) instead of filter `> 0`.

Comment: So how exactly do you invoke this on GHCi? quickCheck (forAll genListOfPos (all (> 0)) comparePower2?

Comment: Define `genPos` and `genListOfPos` with `let` (e.g. `let genPos = ...`) and then you can just  run`quickCheck $ forAll genListOfPos $ all (> 0)`.